# postMessage validation failed error occurring during image upload using react-base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, base64

I am uploading an image and saving it to mongodb but it is showing following error:

> message: "postMessage validation failed: selectedFile: Cast

> name: "ValidationError"

> _message: "postMessage validation failed"

I am using react-base64 on the front end side to upload the image.

```html
<FileBase type="file" multiple={false} onDone={(base64) => setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64})} />
```

And i am adding it to DB via fetch :

```js
let handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(postData);
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/posts/create`, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                // 'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(postData),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((dataFromServer) => {
            console.info(dataFromServer);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));

    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how can i fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FileBase component, you need to do in this way.

You need to destructure the parameter on `onDone`. In this way `onDone={({base64}) => yourFunction()}`

You can use this one.

```
<FileBase type="file" multiple={false} onDone={({base64}) => setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64})} />
```

Comment: Thank you mate. I was able to fix the issue.